# How are virtue and learning related for Confucius?

Tags: confucius

I'm reading *[The Analects](http://www.acmuller.net/con-dao/analects.html)*, by Confucius, and have a question.

According to Confucius, can non-virtue be **learned**?

There's no clear answer to this, so far, in the text.

Comment: I'm not really following the thread of your thinking here. Can you explain why you take these statements to compose a meaningful group from the *Analects*? Also, I'd strongly suggest getting the Slingerland translation which provides helpful commentary from the past on each section. Read in isolation (especially if you don't know Chinese), it's going to be hard to make sense of what you're reading.

Comment: i'm not saying they are a "meaningful group" i'm saying that each ***nearly*** supports the claim that there can be un-virtuous skill. i think that's ***obviouosly*** the case with the second quote, and that if it isn't, then trying to explain further would be pointless. so i would apprecaite a note on if it is obvious @virmaior

Comment: if the question was "what does it mean by clever in the second quote?" then I could answer that, but I don't understand why you're putting the two quotes together or the thrust of your question as written.

Comment: @virmaior the question is the question in the first paragraph (there are no other explicit questions!) -- especially what i say i'm "specifically" aksing. the rest of the question is just trying to demonstrate what i've found out so far, not an answer, but the best i can currently do :)

Comment: @virmaior see this question for the issue you raised https://philosophy.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3404/how-to-get-away-from-what-have-you-found-out-so-far-comments-but-also-not-conf

Comment: Er, there aren't any question marks in the first paragraph.  If by "question", you mean `wondered if the relation between wisdom and virtue could be clearly stated, and specifically if non-virtue can be learned, like a skill is.`, then I'm not grasping what that has to do with the *Analects* and slightly lost as to what it means.

Comment: @virmaior the reason it should be obvious that it's asking about the virtue and wisdom at it appears in the analects has been cut out of your quote "I'm reading The Analects, by Confucius, and wondered". you **have to use your common sense a little**

Comment: Do you mean the **title** to your question? I looked at the first paragraph which is where you suggested to look ...

Comment: @virmaior the opening paragraph repeats the content of **title** which i was helpful enough to include a question mark with. please use your **common sense** -- you obviously have enough skill with the english language for stuff like this to be no issue

Comment: @virmaior if someone starts a thread on a q&a site that says "i wondered what X was" -- you should assume that they are asking the **question** of  what X is

Comment: @virmaior better now?? i suppose that question formats of this sort are an improvement -- thank  you  :)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/56931/discussion-between-user3293056-and-virmaior).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a major topic of debate.

"17.2 The Master said, “By nature people are similar; they diverge as the result of practice."

So clearly if that divergence leads some to be virtuous and other not to be, either:

1. human nature is ultimately bad and can only be improved, or
2. you can learn non-virtue.

Others have disagreed on which of those two things are meant.  Xunzi noted that a lot of the Analects is about practice to make one good, so this may have meant 1.

But the majority opinion seems to go with Mencius, who maintained "human nature is good".  So at least one famous immediate disciple thought this phrase 'obviously' meant 2.

Later commentators backed off from the question.  After all, in practice, it can't really matter: we know that practice can improve the end result, and it is not really germane whether it works by merely cultivating native goodness or whether it inculcates goodness into something basically flawed.  What works to produce the good, works.

Comment: I went back and vacillated after you upvoted me...  Figured it made sense to point that out.